# Is it possible to loop over a stored procedure based on the output parameter?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, while-loop

I have a SQL script which takes the output parameter `yesterday` and returns all the data for that specified date.

Is there a way to execute the stored procedure whilst continuing to loop if the date is less than today's date?

`exec dw.DashboardELT @yesterday = '2020-04-01'`

I'm trying to get data from April 1st 2020 to October 26th.

E.g.

```
while @yesterday < '2020-10-27'
begin
  exec dw.DashboardELT @yesterday = '2020-04-01'
set @yesterday = dateadd(day,1,@yesterday)
end
```

Comment: Yes, and what you have would work if you passed a variable, not a literal, to the parameter  `@yesterday`.

Comment: Just to add to Larnu's input, you'll need a variable, say `DECLARE @runDate date = '20200401'` Pass the variable to your proc, then increment that variable instead of the pseudo coded parameter increment that you have.  You're 99% done already.